# How can I change the default port (8080) on Amazon EC to port 80

Tags: amazon-ec2

I tried to change the default port on my Tomcat, with the `server.xml` file, changing `8080` to `80`. But when I try to visit my application, it is not available. What am I doing wrong? Are there some security issues with Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways to make Tomcat listen on port 80, but not all of them are available on all flavors of Linux.

For details and pointers, see the section [*Running Tomcat on port 80*](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/tomcat-amazon-ec2-advanced.html#port80) in my series of articles on Tomcat on EC2.

Answer (score 6):

Switch to root user via `sudo su -` command. In `/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/tomcat7.conf` change `TOMCAT_USER="tomcat"` to `TOMCAT_USER="root"`. In `/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/server.xml` change `8080` to `80` (and also `8443` to `443` if you’re a perfectionist).

Answer (score 2):

Are you running Tomcat as root? Only root can open port 80. Check if can you access the port locally - eg. try `wget http://localhost/` . Obviously check also if your security group allows access to port 80, but I expect it does if 8080 was available.

Comment: When i tried wget http://localhost : i have 

Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Connection refused.

Comment: So the problem is then on the box itself. Check your firewall settings (iptables -L) and if Tomcat is listening on port 80 (netstat -ntpl)

Comment: When I ran iptables -L I have : 

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen/modules.dep: No such file or directory
iptables v1.4.5: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

Comment: Sory, In fact I have this error message :

FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen/modules.dep: No such file or directory
iptables v1.4.5: can't initialize iptables table `filter': iptables who? (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

Comment: And did netstat show port 80 in listening mode? First error showed you run on non-root. Do you start Tomcat as root? For iptables error I won't help. Maybe you can Google a bit. Here is some thread with the same error: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/iptables-v1-3-8-cant-initialize-iptables-table-%60filter-577212/

Comment: I use this command to start tomcat `sudo service tomcat6 start` but Tomcat doesn't seem to listen on port 80?

Comment: @Miranda: The `tomcat6` service is likely configured to run as user `tomcat`. It is not a good security practice to run Tomcat as root.

Answer (score 2):

To enable this on AWS for tomcat 7.0.33 I modified server.xml as suggested above.

Then update /etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf.
    sudo vi /etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf
change
    TOMCAT_USER="tomcat" to "root"
bounce the server with 
    sudo service tomcat restart

Answer (score 1):

you can use load balancer or set up port forwarding on the linux built in firwall

see this blog

http://charlie.cu.cc/2012/04/how-run-tomcat-port-80-amazon-web-service-aws/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. if you configure the server.xml and open port 80 in ec2 what you have to do is first shutdown the server. be root (sudo su -) and then start the server again and it should work for you.